# Sample space probability

Tags: probability

Assume that the probability that a person is born on any given day is $\dfrac{1}{365}$ (ignoring February $29$). In a group of $100$, what is the expected number of sets of two people that have the same birthday? What is the sample space?

I am a bit confused for that question, any thoughts? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Let $B$ be a *discrete uniform* random variable, with values in $[1,2,3,\ldots,365]$. Each person's birthday is then one of these.

You have a group of $n$ people, and hence $n$ independent birthdays $B_1, B_2, \ldots, B_{100}$. How many pairs $(i,j)$ can you find that $B_i=B_j$?